# mule3 sftp:input-endpoint encoding

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

I'm wondering, is it possible to force mule to "convert" the encoding of the file it is reading? Lets say the file is put on some sftp area and is later read by an:

```
<sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref= .... encoding="Cp1252">
```

This does not really work...

If the file on the sftp area is "UTF8 without BOM" (ANSI as UTF-8), is it possible to convert this to plain old ANSI encoding reading the file?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Mule won't do this conversion for you.

The payload of a message received by a `sftp:inbound-endpoint` is a `java.io.InputStream` so you can create a custom transformer that reads this stream, performs the encoding conversion and outputs either another input stream or a byte array.

Comment: in that logic, im guessing the same for file output aswell? e.g write file with some encoding to disk with some other encoding?

Comment: I guess so yes: read the bytes in one encoding and produce new bytes in a new encoding. It's actually quite fun and useful :) Consider open sourcing your transformer if it is generic enough...

Comment: For me the following works, at least wit a File endpoint:
<file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\files\encoded-file" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Read cp endcoded file" encoding="Cp1252" mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>


The file to string transformer does the trick for me.